# Where does main function get allocated?

Tags: process, c

When concerned with a memory layout for a process, all function calls within the process get a new stack-frame into the stack.

I'm not sure if this is true for `main` function as it seems like `main` does more things than serving as an entry-point function.

Does `main` function also gets its own stack-frame upon initialization of the a new process?

If this is implementation specific details, explanation for a typical Linux implementation would be useful.

Comment: Usually `_start` is the entry point rather than `main` - see[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29694564/what-is-the-use-of-start-in-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29694564/what-is-the-use-of-start-in-c)

Comment: Subroutines share a stack (They have to): If they had different stack, then which stack would we activated when a subroutine returns? And `main` is just another subroutine, it is call by `_start`.

Comment: This is a general C/C++ language programming question rather than a Unix & Linux one, as it applies to, and could be asked in this very form about, C/C++ language programming on a lot of platforms.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor If `main` is just another subroutine, can I also say that it follows the same step with `non-main` functions when it comes to memory stack allocation?

Comment: @JdeBP I thought it was `kernel` that bootstraps things including memory layout upon process initialization, so UNIX & Linux was more adequate forum to ask about. C language itself doesn't have any authority over where and how it(the program itself) gets allocated/managed.

Comment: @gnis yes, but you are wrong about your idea of a stack. Subroutines don't have one each, they share it. They do however have a stackframe ( a bit of memory that is on the stack, that they can use).

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor Yes, you are right. By "stack", I was referring to "stackframe". Thank you for the correction. Then `main` function has its own stackframe just like other functions?

Comment: @gnis I am happy with the question being here. However the kernel does not do as much as you may think. There is code in the process run before `main` (generated by the C compiler, but not part of the C program), that does a lot. There is even code run before `exec` (before the C program runs).

Comment: @gnis yes it has its own stack frame: it is just another subroutine (function).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91166/discussion-between-gnis-and-ctrl-alt-delor).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually `_start` is the entry point rather than main.

`main` is just another subroutine, it is call by `_start`. It gets a stack-frame, on the stack, just like any other subroutine.

However the kernel does not do as much as you may think. There is code in the process run before main (it `_start` it is generated by the C compiler, but not part of the C program), that does a lot. There is even code run before `exec` (before the C program runs), such as setting up `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr`.

The kernel may do some tricks with `_start`, it can not be run like other subroutines, but it will look like it is: The kernel will set up the process as if `_entry` had just been called (but it was not). If control passes back to `_start` then `exit` is called.

(I may have glossed over some detail, including `_entry`).